# How to get average difference between MySQL table 2 columns where one column is lowest?

Tags: mysql, average

I have one `sales` table with 4 columns:

```
id | item_id | department_id | bought_at | sold_at
```

All columns are `INT(11)`.

items can be bought all the time, but I would like to know the average of the quickest sales for one department. Per item, bought_at are all the same.

Any suggestion how to do this in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by quickest sail, you mean `stored_at` and `sold_at` are nearly equal. If you want average number of quickest sales per item for a department, then use the following query (assuming `department_id` for which we want to find average is `1`,  also assuming the threshold for sold difference as `10`)

```
SELECT AVG(sales_count) average_sales FROM 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS sales_count 
            FROM sales 
            WHERE department_id = 1 AND (sold_at - stored_at) < 10
            GROUP BY item_id
    ) counts
```

Comment: I see the confuzing terms>>> stored_at means STORED IN WHEREHOUSE not in Database.

So, with quickest sale I mean where sold_at - stored_at = x and X is the lowest number. If stored_at = sold_at, the item would be sold the moment we have it in our wherehouse.

Comment: @Glooh Edited the answer. You can use `(sold_at - stored_at) < x` instead of `sold_at = stored_at`.

Comment: this would only return sales that have taken place no more than 10 seconds after we bought them. Also, GROUP may not 100% take a sale that is the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work :-

```
select department_id, avg(sold_at-bought_at) as avg_time
from sales
group by department_id
order by avg_time;
```